# Adding sections such as Linkedin and Github to a Moderncv footer

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

How do I add extra links to the footer of a `moderncv` document that are not covered by the default commands?

Comment: Please give us more details about the final look of the document. If they were available what would you expect to appear and where do you expect to see them? Best is to include a snapshot of the layout you have in mind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one way to do it adding to new fields `\github` and `\linkedin`; the information will be automatically added to the footer, with hyperlinks and some logos (for the logos I used the images obtained with the code at the end of this answer):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\linkedin}[1]{\def\@linkedin{#1}}
\newcommand*{\github}[1]{\def\@github{#1}}
\newcommand*{\externallink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{#2}{#1}}}
\newcommand\githublogo{\raisebox{-1pt}{\includegraphics[height=9pt]{github}}\ }
\newcommand\linkedinlogo{\raisebox{-1pt}{\includegraphics[height=9pt]{linkedin}}\ }

\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}\flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\addtofooter{\mobilesymbol\@mobile}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\addtofooter{\phonesymbol\@phone}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\addtofooter{\faxsymbol\@fax}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@linkedin}}{}{\addtofooter{\linkedinlogo\externallink{\@linkedin}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@github}}{}{\addtofooter{\githublogo\externallink{\@github}}}%
        \flushfooter}}}%

  \pagestyle{plain}}


\moderncvcolor{blue}


\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resume title (optional)}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\linkedin{http://co.linkedin.com/in/johndoe}
\github{http://github.com/jdoe}
\quote{Some quote (optional)}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

The resulting footer:

[image]

The code used to produce the logos (kindly provided by **Paulo Cereda**):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\github}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.8pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,opacity=0.4]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(506.69823,386.92617)}]
    \path[fill=black] (116.9933,59.7217) .. controls (116.9933,71.2283) and
      (107.6655,80.5562) .. (96.1589,80.5562) .. controls (84.6524,80.5562) and
      (75.3245,71.2283) .. (75.3245,59.7217) .. controls (75.3245,48.2152) and
      (84.6524,38.8873) .. (96.1589,38.8873) .. controls (107.6654,38.8873) and
      (116.9933,48.2152) .. (116.9933,59.7217) -- cycle;
    \path[cm={{0.88462,0.0,0.0,0.88462,(11.09526,6.89097)}},fill=white]
      (116.9933,59.7217) .. controls (116.9933,71.2283) and (107.6655,80.5562) ..
      (96.1589,80.5562) .. controls (84.6524,80.5562) and (75.3245,71.2283) ..
      (75.3245,59.7217) .. controls (75.3245,48.2152) and (84.6524,38.8873) ..
      (96.1589,38.8873) .. controls (107.6654,38.8873) and (116.9933,48.2152) ..
      (116.9933,59.7217) -- cycle;
    \path[fill=black,nonzero rule] (103.4671,45.2878) .. controls (102.9322,45.4374)
      and (101.2003,46.2576) .. (100.5403,46.6739) -- (100.1099,46.9454) --
      (99.4882,46.8019) .. controls (99.0810,46.7080) and (98.1204,46.6415) ..
      (96.7048,46.6094) .. controls (94.4953,46.5593) and (93.4339,46.6361) ..
      (92.2380,46.9324) -- (91.6450,47.0793) -- (90.9468,46.6426) .. controls
      (90.0955,46.1101) and (88.7784,45.4948) .. (88.1825,45.3512) .. controls
      (87.9348,45.2916) and (87.5225,45.2429) .. (87.2643,45.2429) .. controls
      (86.8530,45.2429) and (86.7816,45.2733) .. (86.6817,45.4916) .. controls
      (86.3049,46.3144) and (86.1702,48.1697) .. (86.3982,49.3940) --
      (86.5087,49.9870) -- (86.0485,50.6088) .. controls (85.4184,51.4600) and
      (84.9876,52.3958) .. (84.8509,53.2104) .. controls (84.6439,54.4443) and
      (84.8398,57.3849) .. (85.1880,58.2702) .. controls (85.2564,58.4443) and
      (85.2939,58.4403) .. (81.6976,58.6338) .. controls (79.2203,58.7672) and
      (77.4880,58.9815) .. (77.2948,59.1788) .. controls (77.1683,59.3080) and
      (77.2021,59.3161) .. (77.6325,59.2604) .. controls (79.8802,58.9695) and
      (83.0680,58.7293) .. (84.6818,58.7293) .. controls (85.3322,58.7293) and
      (85.3437,58.7337) .. (85.4709,59.0402) .. controls (85.5424,59.2123) and
      (85.5936,59.3574) .. (85.5857,59.3654) .. controls (85.5778,59.3733) and
      (84.8826,59.4288) .. (84.0409,59.4888) .. controls (82.1375,59.6245) and
      (80.3024,59.8884) .. (78.6942,60.2577) .. controls (77.5177,60.5279) and
      (77.1884,60.6573) .. (77.3264,60.7953) .. controls (77.3578,60.8267) and
      (77.9386,60.7190) .. (78.6081,60.5575) .. controls (80.6932,60.0548) and
      (83.4463,59.6858) .. (85.1122,59.6858) .. controls (85.7817,59.6858) and
      (85.8050,59.6938) .. (85.9497,59.9727) .. controls (86.1509,60.3606) and
      (87.1973,61.4638) .. (87.6756,61.7923) .. controls (88.7575,62.5354) and
      (90.1146,63.0487) .. (91.7311,63.3262) .. controls (92.3241,63.4280) and
      (92.8529,63.5117) .. (92.9028,63.5117) .. controls (92.9519,63.5117) and
      (92.8171,63.7221) .. (92.6084,63.9708) .. controls (92.2151,64.4395) and
      (91.8427,65.1574) .. (91.8393,65.4534) .. controls (91.8343,65.8877) and
      (90.1911,66.2247) .. (89.1390,66.0071) .. controls (88.4365,65.8618) and
      (87.9449,65.5203) .. (87.3370,64.7552) .. controls (86.5997,63.8274) and
      (86.0013,63.2318) .. (85.6000,63.0268) .. controls (85.1313,62.7874) and
      (84.1718,62.7744) .. (83.9782,63.0048) .. controls (83.8657,63.1387) and
      (83.8975,63.1954) .. (84.2322,63.4586) .. controls (85.1908,64.2122) and
      (85.6680,64.7934) .. (86.1681,65.8169) .. controls (86.7336,66.9742) and
      (87.2885,67.5731) .. (88.1825,67.9913) .. controls (88.6992,68.2330) and
      (88.8042,68.2463) .. (90.1911,68.2463) -- (91.6546,68.2463) --
      (91.6259,70.0923) -- (91.5972,71.9383) -- (91.2050,72.2922) .. controls
      (90.9850,72.4908) and (90.6785,72.7603) .. (90.5068,72.9061) .. controls
      (90.0483,73.2955) and (90.1529,73.4104) .. (90.9946,73.4418) .. controls
      (91.6450,73.4662) and (91.7691,73.4390) .. (92.3241,73.1503) .. controls
      (93.3630,72.6098) and (93.3667,72.5983) .. (93.3667,69.8628) .. controls
      (93.3667,67.3377) and (93.4455,66.7059) .. (93.8107,66.3047) --
      (94.0458,66.0464) -- (93.9980,69.2506) .. controls (93.9695,71.1540) and
      (93.9075,72.6024) .. (93.8449,72.8183) .. controls (93.7868,73.0192) and
      (93.6134,73.3252) .. (93.4575,73.5022) .. controls (93.3059,73.6744) and
      (93.1754,73.9155) .. (93.1754,74.0235) .. controls (93.1754,74.1976) and
      (93.2328,74.2243) .. (93.6058,74.2243) .. controls (94.3519,74.2243) and
      (95.3191,73.5586) .. (95.6209,72.8374) .. controls (95.8285,72.3417) and
      (95.9492,70.6280) .. (95.9492,68.1794) -- (95.9492,65.9029) --
      (96.4179,65.9029) -- (96.4465,69.1311) .. controls (96.4752,72.3544) and
      (96.4756,72.3599) .. (96.7144,72.8374) .. controls (97.1209,73.6505) and
      (98.5189,74.4873) .. (99.0195,74.2173) .. controls (99.2785,74.0776) and
      (99.2470,73.9374) .. (98.8154,73.3061) .. controls (98.5996,72.9905) and
      (98.3935,72.5452) .. (98.3372,72.2731) .. controls (98.2088,71.6514) and
      (98.2544,66.1949) .. (98.3882,66.1752) .. controls (98.4417,66.1673) and
      (98.5682,66.3047) .. (98.6752,66.4864) .. controls (98.8508,66.7849) and
      (98.8704,67.0316) .. (98.9143,69.4898) .. controls (98.9477,71.3645) and
      (98.9985,72.2310) .. (99.0833,72.3783) .. controls (99.2883,72.7344) and
      (99.9568,73.2398) .. (100.3777,73.3570) .. controls (100.6002,73.4189) and
      (101.0568,73.4562) .. (101.4011,73.4406) .. controls (102.2046,73.4043) and
      (102.2524,73.2299) .. (101.5924,72.7428) .. controls (100.6531,72.0496) and
      (100.6840,72.1775) .. (100.6746,68.9637) .. controls (100.6656,65.9699) and
      (100.6109,65.4703) .. (100.2007,64.6499) .. controls (100.0812,64.4108) and
      (99.8134,64.0644) .. (99.5982,63.8704) -- (99.2108,63.5213) --
      (99.6603,63.4617) .. controls (100.5690,63.3414) and (102.0372,63.0328) ..
      (102.6446,62.8345) .. controls (104.1654,62.3382) and (105.5084,61.3208) ..
      (106.1445,60.1832) -- (106.4227,59.6858) -- (106.9679,59.6858) .. controls
      (108.9956,59.6858) and (112.7503,60.2177) .. (114.7632,60.7901) .. controls
      (114.9162,60.8337) and (114.9832,60.8090) .. (114.9832,60.7092) .. controls
      (114.9832,60.3420) and (111.4059,59.7105) .. (108.1061,59.4950) .. controls
      (107.2931,59.4419) and (106.6181,59.3838) .. (106.5996,59.3654) .. controls
      (106.5815,59.3473) and (106.6145,59.1932) .. (106.6713,59.0306) --
      (106.7765,58.7293) -- (107.9817,58.7323) .. controls (109.6496,58.7363) and
      (111.7789,58.8872) .. (113.5293,59.1252) .. controls (114.8684,59.3073) and
      (115.2129,59.3130) .. (115.0501,59.1502) .. controls (114.8456,58.9456) and
      (112.1137,58.6482) .. (109.3399,58.5285) .. controls (108.0008,58.4707) and
      (106.8944,58.4168) .. (106.8865,58.4089) .. controls (106.8785,58.4010) and
      (106.9394,58.0694) .. (107.0204,57.6772) .. controls (107.1184,57.2030) and
      (107.1719,56.3764) .. (107.1782,55.2382) .. controls (107.1862,53.7174) and
      (107.1624,53.4295) .. (106.9708,52.7704) .. controls (106.6953,51.8235) and
      (106.3173,51.0734) .. (105.7225,50.2931) -- (105.2557,49.6810) --
      (105.2940,48.0598) .. controls (105.3295,46.5581) and (105.3160,46.3927) ..
      (105.1123,45.8168) -- (104.8923,45.1951) -- (104.4140,45.1760) .. controls
      (104.1462,45.1653) and (103.7296,45.2145) .. (103.4671,45.2879) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\linkedin}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.8pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,opacity=0.4]
  \begin{scope}[cm={{0.59444,0.0,0.0,0.59444,(346.38938,123.06674)}}]
    \path[fill=black] (380.7408,201.6221) -- (434.0804,201.6221) .. controls
      (438.6572,201.6221) and (442.3417,205.3067) .. (442.3417,209.8835) --
      (442.3417,263.5823) .. controls (442.3417,268.1591) and (438.6572,271.8436) ..
      (434.0804,271.8436) -- (380.7408,271.8436) .. controls (376.1640,271.8436) and
      (372.4794,268.1591) .. (372.4794,263.5823) -- (372.4794,209.8835) .. controls
      (372.4794,205.3067) and (376.1640,201.6221) .. (380.7408,201.6221) -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}[xscale=0.981,yscale=1.019,fill=white]
      \path[fill=white] (402.5597,253.0812) -- (402.5597,223.9631) --
        (393.5086,223.9631) -- (393.5086,253.0812) -- cycle(398.0937,211.3394) ..
        controls (396.6162,211.3680) and (395.4476,211.8021) .. (394.5879,212.6419) ..
        controls (393.7282,213.4818) and (393.2891,214.5561) .. (393.2705,215.8649) ..
        controls (393.2879,217.1476) and (393.7146,218.2145) .. (394.5507,219.0655) ..
        controls (395.3868,219.9165) and (396.5281,220.3581) .. (397.9746,220.3904) ..
        controls (399.5067,220.3582) and (400.7001,219.9165) .. (401.5548,219.0655) ..
        controls (402.4095,218.2145) and (402.8437,217.1476) .. (402.8574,215.8649) ..
        controls (402.8152,214.5561) and (402.3785,213.4818) .. (401.5474,212.6419) ..
        controls (400.7162,211.8021) and (399.5650,211.3679) .. (398.0937,211.3394) --
        cycle;
      \path[fill=white] (409.7910,253.0812) -- (418.8420,253.0812) --
        (418.8420,236.2892) .. controls (418.8400,235.8674) and (418.8594,235.4605) ..
        (418.9015,235.0685) .. controls (418.9437,234.6765) and (419.0231,234.3291) ..
        (419.1397,234.0264) .. controls (419.4635,233.1556) and (420.0068,232.3815) ..
        (420.7698,231.7041) .. controls (421.5327,231.0268) and (422.5375,230.6695) ..
        (423.7843,230.6323) .. controls (425.4081,230.6609) and (426.5817,231.2439) ..
        (427.3049,232.3815) .. controls (428.0282,233.5190) and (428.3830,235.0400) ..
        (428.3693,236.9442) -- (428.3693,253.0812) -- (437.4203,253.0812) --
        (437.4203,235.8724) .. controls (437.3582,231.5975) and (436.3658,228.4316) ..
        (434.4430,226.3748) .. controls (432.5202,224.3180) and (430.0391,223.2958) ..
        (426.9998,223.3081) .. controls (424.5633,223.3851) and (422.6033,223.9309) ..
        (421.1196,224.9456) .. controls (419.6359,225.9604) and (418.5988,226.9826) ..
        (418.0083,228.0123) -- (417.8297,228.0123) -- (417.4129,223.9631) --
        (409.5528,223.9631) .. controls (409.6148,225.2695) and (409.6694,226.6911) ..
        (409.7165,228.2281) .. controls (409.7636,229.7652) and (409.7884,231.4399) ..
        (409.7909,233.2523) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\linkedin\github
\end{document}
```

Comment: So much code for a square with rounded corners (and then some)? Is this really the best way to define the symbols? I wonder how Paulo did that.

Comment: @mafp I initially considered using scaled versions of existing images for the logos (and a simple `\includegraphics`), but I wasn't sure if one can do that with the logos, so I asked Paulo to generate the figures in some other way.

Comment: [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.uib.no/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.pdf) has both Github (`\faGithub`) and LinkedIn (`\faLinkedin`) as well as a few other social network icons.

Comment: @You yes, I know; this question was asked, and its answer was provided, at a time when those were not available in `moderncv`.

Comment: I don't know if my questions justfies to post a new questions, so I just add a comment. It was already discussed in other questions that `moderncv` is missing built in Xing support. Neither `\fontawesome` supplies the Xing-icon. @Gonzalo I managed to create a further Xing-entry in the footer by adding following code in the preamble `\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@xing}}{}{\addtofooter{\xinglogo\href{www.xing.de/profile/john_doe}{\@xing}}}%` However the link is not working properly when applying `\href{www.xing.de/profile/john_doe}`. Using just `\href{www.xing.de}` without slashes works fine.

Comment: @user49794 Feel free to open a fresh new question.

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT** This solution was already mentioned by @you in the comments, i just overlooked that.

---

I'm just going to address the tikz drawings of the linkedin and github logo in the answer of @GonzaloMedina and provide a more simple version.

The [fontawesome](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome) package provides some nice symbols for linkedin, github and lots of more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
test
\faGithub 
\faLinkedin
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 8):

As a general rule, you can add any type of additional information using the `\extrainfo` command, e.g.

```
\extrainfo{%
  \httplink{www.linkedin.com/in/johndoe}
  \httplink{www.github.com/johndoe}}
```

This works whatever the style of your resume or letter. You can obviously add pictures or symbols or before the links.

Finally, in case you are using the `casual` style, the command to produce the bullets that are used to separate footer items is `\footersymbol`.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone arrives here wanting to put the LinkedIn link in the top left header, you can use the `\social` command already included in Moderncv. Taken from [this example](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/examples/template.tex) in the "manual":

```
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[xing]{john\_doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}
\social[skype]{jdoe}
```

You can also [customize the url](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/2033517d3f29f9c16af1b3421d52f281e94aa2a5/moderncv.cls#L258) using something like:

```
\social[linkedin][www.linkedin.com/in/myname/]{My name}
```