# social links and symbols in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

how does one add more more social links and their associated icon/symbol(e.g codeplex, bitbucket) in moderncv.

I tried to include this:

```
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{codeplex}}  {\collectionadd[codeplex]{socials} 
           {\protect\httplink[#3]{www.codeplex.com/#3}}}     {}%
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70216/adding-sections-such-as-linkedin-and-github-to-a-moderncv-footer is also similar I guess.