# place text right of vertical line and below of picture

Tags: floats, positioning

I have this code (I simplified my code - the \github command is provided by [this tikz code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70286/76157). ):

```
\documentclass[11cm,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey

% <<<tikz block for the github logo>>>   

\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\vspace{-1cm}
\noindent
\hspace{0.2\textwidth}%
\textcolor{color1}{\rule[-.5\textwidth]{5pt}{\textwidth}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}%
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[]{/home/toogley/bew/img/passbilder/platzhalter.png}}
\github{github.com/toogley}

\end{document}
```

which produces this image: [image]

i want to place the github logo, its text and a bunch of other things directly below the picture and right of the vertical line. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your picture and text below it in `\parbox` or in `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[11cm,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey

% <<<tikz block for the github logo>>>
\usepackage{lipsum}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\hspace{0.2\textwidth}%
\textcolor{color1}{\rule[-.5\textwidth]{5pt}{\textwidth}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}%
\parbox{0.75\textwidth}{
                       \includegraphics[width=0.5\hsize]{example-image-a}\\
                       \lipsum[2]
                       }
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If you like to have picture on the middle, enclose it in `\centerline{...}`:

```
\parbox{0.75\textwidth}{
        \centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.5\hsize]{example-image-a}}
        \lipsum[2]
                       }
```

As can be seen, I simulate your picture with `example-image-a` from `graphicx` package and your stuff under it with dummy text from `lipsum` package. Also the `\raisebox` is omitted since it is not necessary.